# WebClient (403) Forbidden

Tags: c#

I'm using Dropbox to store my files and when I use a direct link I get a HTTP redirect. But I'm able to get the redirect URI with...

```
            var request = WebRequest.Create(MySQLData);
            request.Method = "HEAD";
            var response = request.GetResponse();
```

However I get "The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden." So then I added a User-Agent header, but it still returned the same error. I'm not sure what to try next.

```
  WebClient wc = new WebClient();
            wc.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(MySQLData_Check);
            wc.DownloadFileCompleted += DownloadCompleted_MySQLData;

            var request = WebRequest.Create(MySQLData);
            request.Method = "HEAD";
            var response = request.GetResponse();


            wc.Headers.Add("User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)");
            wc.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(response.ResponseUri.ToString()), RootWindow_TextBox_SaveToDir.Text + "/" + "MySQLData");
```

Comment: Going through a proxy? Or are you bypassing proxy?

Comment: @NeillVerreynne I'm not going through a proxy, or bypassing one.

Comment: Try to change the header to: wc.Headers.Add("User-Agent: Other")

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was because I was using ?raw=1, rather than ?dl=1 in the URI string.

For example...

```
string MyDownload = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/********/MyFile.zip?dl=1";
```